# Understanding PHP Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a website, and the user has just logged in and it redirects them to the User Dashboard.  I have the user_id in a SESSION so I can use that for my SELECT queries to grab other information about the user.

My question is, how can I use Prepared Statments to just grab the variables that I need for that page, without using a foreach statement or a while statement.  It will just be for that specific user logged in, not displaying information for multiple users.

**Every example I look up is like this:**

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 150,5";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

/* execute statement */
$stmt->execute();

/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($name, $code);

/* fetch values */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Does it have to be in a while statement?  I just need the variables at the top, so I can display my regular page and then use the variables when I need to.  Does that make sense?

Just looking to learn more and get a better understanding of how this works.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "variables at the top"?

Comment: That's not a good example of prepared statements. It's basically just a fancy way to retrieve the result sets right into the local variable scope.

Comment: That `while` statement is just grabbing each record one at a time. If you're only retrieving one record, you don't need a loop at all. How you retrieve all needed information for that one user depends on how the user data is stored in your database. Can you show us your database structure?

Comment: Well the database holds information like Company Name, Address, Zip Code, Email Address, Phone, Website URL.  I want to show that information on the dashboard page.  What I meant by at the top was just declaring like $company = $row['company']; and $address = $row['address']; for all of the variables I need to display on that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the top record:

```
/* fetch values */
$stmt->fetch();
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
```

`$stmt->fetch` will fetch the first row, you don't need the `while` unless you want to continue through all the rows.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that once and it didn't work but I realized it was because I was echoing the variables like <?=$var;?> and kept getting an error and then changed it to <?php echo $var; ?> and it worked!